# Excel If-Statement returning True Statement although Logic-Test returns "False"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following If-Statement to evaluate if a date is below 1901 or above 2098. Using `Date(2099;31;12)` does not work - it always interprets the 2098 as 1905, thus the value 72000.

```
=IF(OR(W88<=DATE(1900;31;12);W88>=72000);"Not Valid";"")
```

However, despite the date being inside the range (example 2005), the if returns the wrong statement. First I thought it was a logic error but the formula evaluation clearly shows that the logic test leads to the correct result: False. Nevertheless, the output remains "Not valid".

[image]
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue, but was not able to do so. Seems to be a temporary problem or bug. Try to: restart Excel; delete formula and type it again; update your Excel to latest version. Please let us know if your problem is solved.

Comment: What is in W88? With the proper arguments in the DATE function (YMD), I cannot reproduce your problem.  Also, instead of using the tool, type the logic portion separately in a cell and see what it returns.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I did not get to fix the problem but moved everything to a new excel file and it works now, super strange. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug or some kind of error, I recreated my sheet in a new file and the issue is gone. Super strange. Thanks everyone for the help!